# Wait for angular js factory request to get response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular in my rails application, Below is snippet of code which make a api request and code in .run is executed. There are times when the api response is still pending and the code is executed. This results in the directives not getting loading properly as expected. for ex- ng-if depends on some data for things to be loaded but since data is not available. It misses to display the messages.

```
}).factory('ApiDataCall', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('api_data/check_errors');

}).run(function ($rootScope, $timeout, $navigationWarning,$window, ApiDataCall) {

  ApiDataCall.get(function (data) {
    $rootScope.require_redirect = data;
  });
```

I would like to know how can i put a delay to confirm the request is completed. I found that $q.defer() along with promise can solve this issue but could not figure out the approach. Let me know if any other inputs required from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApiDataCall needs to return an Angular promise. Then you can do something like:

```
ApiDataCall.get(function (data) {
    $rootScope.require_redirect = data;
    }).then(function success(response) {
        //Do something here that requires ApiDataCall.get() to complete 
    }, function failure(response) {
       //Do something here if the call fails.
    }
);
```

An easy way to implement promises is using $q. for instance 
having ApiDataCall.get return:

```
return $q.when({foo: "bar"});
```

for a success. and:

```
return $q.reject();
```

for a failure

allows for the response object passed to the respective functions in then() to be {foo: "bar"}